# Facebook Game Request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk, fbsdk

I am trying to implement the Facebook Game Request documentation into my Swift project but I am:

A) unsure if I need Unity to do this or if I can do this just with my IOS application and

B) How to implement the correct dialog that opens the Facebook Game Request (the note in the documentation seems outdated)

I have looked at the docs and I'm still a little confused. If anyone could provide further guidance it would be much appreciated!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/gamerequests#invites

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Unity, it can be done in Swift. Completely agree that the documentation in outdated.

to open the dialog to send a request you can use the following code (change message and whatever you want to change)

```
func sendLifeRequest(index: Int) {
    let content = FBSDKGameRequestContent()
    content.message = "Please help me with 5 lives"
    content.data = "5lives"
    let id = facebookFriends[index].id as NSString
    var to: [NSString] = [NSString]()
    to.append(id)
    content.recipients = to
    FBSDKGameRequestDialog.show(with: content, delegate: self)
}
```

also, make sure you have this three functions in your FBSDKGameRequestDialogDelegate (they are required)

```
func gameRequestDialog(_ gameRequestDialog: FBSDKGameRequestDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print("request sent")
}

func gameRequestDialog(_ gameRequestDialog: FBSDKGameRequestDialog!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print("error sending request")
    print(error)
}

func gameRequestDialogDidCancel(_ gameRequestDialog: FBSDKGameRequestDialog!) {
    print("request canceled")
}
```

Hope that helped...

Comment: thanks for your reply! i already had the delegate methods in place, but would really appreciate if you could clarify what facebookFriends is? Obviously a varable defined elsewhere, but I am trying to

Comment: figure out where that variable came from and what data is currently stored in it

Comment: last question: do you know if there's any way to add custom UI to the FBSDKGameRequestDialog? I've checked the documentation and all I see is that's possible for invitablefriends, which I cannot use since I do not have my app built across multiple platforms

Comment: facebookFriends is an Array with information from the friends I store this information during login and it is only the friends that use my app. In this part I use the friend's ID only. What do you mean by a custom UI? Do you want to send the request without opening the Facebook app? I don't know if you can... but I don't think so

Comment: Are you reading the notifications from the receiver end by any chance? I have been trying to get the data or other information on the receiver end but couldn't find a way...